# Why list::push_back much slower in VC++ than g++？

Tags: c++, performance, list, visual-c++, g++

This code takes about 20 seconds in my VS2012, but only 1.x seconds in G++.
Both in win8 x64 and compiled with default options.

```
list<double> items;
for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
    items.push_back(rand());
}
cout<<"done"<<endl;
```

Is it something about memory allocation? It takes 3~5 seconds to release memory after the ouput in VC++ in my machine, and even more than 1 minute in my firend's (win7 x64).

Comment: I am not sure what the default build config for G++ is, but for Visual Studio it's **DEBUG** and you don't want to compare performance of debug builds

Comment: How about compiling with Release in VS, and -O2 option with gcc?

Comment: did you try to do `items.reserve(10000000)` right before the loop?

Comment: @aleguna There is no `reserve()` in `list`; you're thinking `vector`.

Comment: How did you measure time? Post the *actual* code.

Comment: Why is this being voted down? It's a perfectly valid question with a definite answer, and cleanly stated.

Comment: @aleguna there is no reserve for std::list

Comment: bear in mind that an optimized compilation might see that items is unused and discard the entire loop....

Comment: Take ~2 seconds in Release Build.

Comment: @emartel Much faster when compling with Realease. Can you please explian what's the differece?

Comment: @raulchen your `debug` build is simply not optimized, as `release` has some optimizations turned on by default. Compare both project configurations in Visual C++ to learn the differences

Comment: Doesn't the debug build in VC make operator[] equivilant to at( )?

Answer (score 13):

Hmm...I expanded your code to include timing:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() { 
    std::list<double> items;

    clock_t start = clock();

    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        items.push_back(rand());
    }

    clock_t finish = clock();

    std::cout << "Time: " << double(finish-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with VC++ using: `cl /O2b2 /GL test_list.cpp`

Likewise, I compiled with g++, using: `g++ -O3 test_list.cpp`

Then I ran the two.

With VC++ I got: `Time: 1.293`.
With g++ I got: `Time: 1.313`.

That's a small enough difference that I think I'd need to test quite a bit more to be at all certain of saying VC++ produced significantly *faster* code, but I think it's enough to support a conclusion that VC++ is *not* producing significantly *slower* code.

You need to turn on optimization for timing results to mean anything.

Comment: Thanks. My code is almost like this. The problem's the DEBUG compling option.

Comment: @raulchen Debug is *meant* to be slow so that it can be *debugged*.

Comment: @Mystical What debug is *meant* for is to choose "noisy" errors to inform the developer of a potential problem rather than perform a handling appropriate to field deployment.  99% of the time this will be slower, but a release build is certainly free to react to an unexpected condition in a way that is slower.  I mention in part because I actually *don't believe in the debug/release distinction* (!), assert, or verify: http://hostilefork.com/hoist/

Comment: @HostileFork: what a coincidence, just yesterday I named a thingy (to keep track of file, linenumber and function) `CodePlace`. maybe i read your article earlier. hope you don't have patent or copyright on the name! :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'd **never** patent anything so narrow!!!  *(That's why I have worldwide exclusive rights on declarations starting with "c" and ending with "e"--upper and lower case.  Once I finalize the settlement with those people who had the gall to call one of their classes `CacheEngine`, you'll be hearing from my lawyer.)*

Answer (score -5):

If you're on Windows and worry about performance, don't use STL containers. Functionally-equivalent ATL container classes are usually *much* faster.

On my laptop (i5-2410M CPU, Windows 7 64) your example (when compiled in Release build with visual studio 2010 for 64 bits) executes in 740 milliseconds. When using functionally-equivalent ATL container [CAtlList<double>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kc8a6xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the execution time drops to just 370 milliseconds.

Performance penalty for using standard libraries is about 50%, when compared to premium libraries by Microsoft.

Here's the source code:

```
void list_stl()
{
    std::list<double> items;
    CBenchmarkTimer tt( "10M doubles in std::list" );
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
        items.push_back( rand() );
    tt.End();
}

void list_atl()
{
    CAtlList<double> items;
    CBenchmarkTimer tt( "10M doubles in CAtlList" );
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ )
        items.AddTail( rand() );
    tt.End();
}
```

CBenchmarkTimer is my own class that uses high-resolution timer.

Comment: I doubt they are functionally equivalent if it's that much faster, but I also doubt it's that much faster though...

Comment: How exactly is the C++ standard library "open source"?

Comment: @MooingDuck, I've added the source code - if you doubt, feel free to test yourself. And yes, they're functionally equivalent, see the documentation for CAtlList.

Comment: Why "-"? Compile the code and test yourself. CAtlList adds elements 2 times faster, iterates elements 10%-12% faster.